# ReSharper auto-complete behavior with anonymous types in a lambda expression

Tags: autocomplete, lambda, resharper, anonymous-types

I am using C# 3.5 and Linq.  I have ReSharper 6.1 on VS 2010.

For example, if I enter the following statement in the code editor:

```
var result = dataContext.Items.Select(i => new {Name = i.ItemName});
```

As soon as I type the `new {` it auto-completes to `new string{}`.  Actually, not sure if it is always `string` or depends on the lambda.  But I find I always need to delete it and back up.  This happens whenever I am declaring anonymous types in a lambda.

What setting in ReSharper or VS do I need to change in order to be able to enter anonymous types using the above syntax without that occurring?  Preferably, I would like to retain auto-completing in all other situations, just not this particular one as it is making an incorrect assumption as to my intent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Resharper 6.1 added a new feature to control the way the intellisense autopopups act. Go to ReSharper->Options->Environment->IntelliSense->Autopopup and change the "After 'new'" setting to "Display but do not preselect".

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for showing me something new.

Comment: This is really useful! I was searching for a similar setting (if you are doing LINQ [VB Syntax here], and type `Dim thing = (From x In stuff)`, it would auto-populate the `x` to `Xor`

Comment: Stumbled upon this while searching for something else and instantly added to team settings. Thanks for showing how to get rid of this annoyance!

Comment: And again, needed this answer. Wish I could vote it up twice!